# My antivirus makes my test server recompile constantly

Tags: asp.net

I just installed PC Tools Anti-Virus and my ASP.NET website recompiles everything before every page load.

Which folder are asp.net website files in, so that i can prevent this from happening?

And, i'm probly not the first person with this kind of error, so is there a common solution for this?

Thank you,
-Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this happens as the Anti-Virus probably changes the datetime stamp of the file. You shall have to exclude the entire virtual directory or the site folder from revisiting.

You can see some other issues of web application recycling here: http://www.geekays.net/post/ASPNET-webdomain-recycle-on-subfolder-changes.aspx

Comment: Thnx for all the info! Do I exclude where I keep my site files, or do I add an exclude to the ASP.net temp folder?

Comment: Exclude the site files please.